# Pyspark not reading from Kafka Stream

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I am working on reading the stream from a Kafka instance into Pyspark, but the output continues to be blank.  I am able to see the values in a terminal with a Kafka Consumer running, but the console output in Pyspark is blank.  There are no errors.  The Kafka instance is running in a Docker container on port 29092.  I have a terminal set up as a consumer and one as a producer.  When I type something like "Test" into the producer terminal, it shows up in the consumer terminal, but not in the spark stream.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr

# Create a Spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("KafkaStreamWriter") \
    .config('spark.jars.packages', 'org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.4.0') \
    .getOrCreate()

# Define Kafka parameters
kafka_bootstrap_servers = "localhost:29092"  # Replace with your Kafka bootstrap servers

# Generate a DataFrame with numbers from 1 to 100
data = [(i,) for i in range(1, 101)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["number"])

# Write the DataFrame to Kafka topic "first_topic"
df.selectExpr("CAST(number AS STRING) AS value") \
    .write \
    .format("kafka") \
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafka_bootstrap_servers) \
    .option("topic", "taxi_topic") \
    .save()

# Read from Kafka topic "first_topic" and write to the console using a write stream
df = spark \
    .readStream \
    .format("kafka") \
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafka_bootstrap_servers) \
    .option("subscribe", "taxi_topic") \
    .load()

# Convert the value column from Kafka to integer and select it
df = df.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING) AS value").select("value")

# Write the DataFrame to the console using a write stream
query = df \
    .writeStream \
    .outputMode("append") \
    .format("console") \
    .start()

# Wait for the streaming query to finish
query.awaitTermination()
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I guess the issue is that you first write messages to kafka and after that you start stream on that topic. By default for kafka structured streaming option `startingOffsets` is set to latest, which means stream will not first process already present messages. You can try adding `.option("startingOffsets","earliest")` to reader and see what happens. Alternatively you may try with batch read just to test if there are any other issues.